# How do I cut off the front of an integer?

Tags: python

I am trying to show the last 2 digits of an integer. Basically, if I have an input of 1929, it would only display 29. For input 290016, it would display 16.

Answer (score 5):

Modulus.

```
>>> 1929 % 100
29
>>> 290016 % 100
16
```